# Is there a way I can get the highest numbers from the number I gave?

Tags: python

I want to get the highest numbers of my number, for example when I create a function that takes two arguments, a list and a integer, and then I want to print a list that store numbers that are larger than the number.

I created this function, called `isGreater` , but this prints me `['3', '0']` and I don't know even why.

**Example:**

```
def isGreater(myList, num):
    for _ in myList:
        if _ > num:
            return list(str(_))

print(isGreater([1, 30, 25, 60, 27, 28], 28))
```

Comment: You get `['3', '0']` because you are returning `list(str(30))` -> so you get list of individual characters. I would suggest to look at list comprehensions.

Comment: It's unclear why you wrote that line to begin with. Don't [program by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence), think about what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't vote to close as a duplicate; as I (like Andrej, who did vote for the dupe) hold a gold badge in [tag:python], it would have been closed immediately if I had. That said: yes, I did want to shut your question down, but because it's trivial therefore useless to others. I'd recommend taking the [tour] to better understand what SO is for and what kinds of question are appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You're returning immediately when you find the first element that's greater than `num`, instead of returning all the elements that match this criterion.
2. You're using `list(str(_))`. The `list()` function takes a sequence and converts it to a list of the elements. A string is a sequence of its characters, so this turns the `'30'` into the list `['3', '0']`.

When a list element matches your criteria, you should append it to a list that you return at the end.

```
def isGreater(myList, num):
    result = []
    for el in myList:
        if el > num:
            result.append(el)
    return result
```

Note also: `_` is normally used as an iteration variable only when you don't intend to use the variable. So I changed the variable to `el`.

The more pythonic way to write this is using a list comprehension:

```
def isGreater(myList, num):
    return [el for el in myList if el > num]
```

Comment: Thanks! Second solution is not working, you should check it.

Comment: You can try second solution now.

Answer (score 1):

How others said is unclear, but I hope this helps you.

```
def isGreater(myList, targetedNum):
    listOfGreater = []
    for number in myList:
        if number > targetedNum:
            listOfGreater.append(number)
    return listOfGreater

print(isGreater([1, 30, 25, 60, 27, 28], 28))
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to return a list of strings representing integers greater than 28.
In that case you should create the list before the for loop and simply append items to it, then return the new list after the loop.